# Rescue "RecordNotFound" errors in DelayedJob workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, rescue

I use DelayedJob to handle certain tasks in the background.

For example, in my application a user can "like" a message, and when that happens the poster gets notified. This notification is handled in the background.

Occasionally, what can happen is that the liker decides to undo his action and delete his "like" before the notification goes out. In those instances the background code hits a "RecordNotFound" error as the "like" no longer exists.

I thought I handled this case by rescuing the error as so (self here is the Like):

```
  def send_push_notifications
    begin
      user = self.message.user
      message = "#{self.user.name} liked your workout"
      Urbanairship::push_now(user, message, ["message", self.message.id]) if self.user != user
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      # Do nothing
    end
  end
```

However, in practice this does not seem to be rescuing the errors, as I still see such errors in my logs:

```
{ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, class: Like , primary key: 1557 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.2/lib/delayed/serialization/active_record.rb:12:in `rescue in yaml_new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.2/lib/delayed/serialization/active_record.rb:6:in `yaml_new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `transfer'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `node_import'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
```

Any ideas why my rescue statement is not working in this case?

Comment: Does it fail before the Urbanairship::push_now call? Can you paste in the entire stack trace?

Comment: Sorry, here is the full stack trace: https://gist.github.com/pejmanjohn/8cf9f1f1d55a90f1ae39

Comment: Are you really sure the error happens between your `begin` and `rescue`? Try with adding a `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` directly after the `begin`. If that works, and is caught, move it to directly before `rescue` and try. Perhaps that can give you some clues...

Comment: @244an that's a fair point. I tested by adding another begin/rescue on the caller into this method and I still see the issue. Also, here's what I see in DelayedJob, it states that the handler is "send_push_notifications". Any other ideas? https://dl.dropbox.com/u/443447/Screen%20Shot%202013-03-05%20at%205.16.20%20PM.png

Comment: Are you upgraded on everything? DelayedJob is deserializing YAML and all that jazz. Maybe there are incompatibilities there? Other than that, is there a way for you to explicitly call Like#find and to bypass DJ's built-in stuff.

Comment: DelayedJob is on the latest stable (3.0.5) but my delayed_job_active_record gem is behind (on 0.3.3). Let me try upgrading and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Updated to delayed_job_active_record to 0.4.3 and still seeing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this by using a class method instead of an instance method for my delay calls. Let me show you by way of example. Here's how I previously structured my delay calls:

```
  def background_send_push_notifications
    self.delay.send_push_notifications
  end

  def send_push_notifications
    message = "#{self.user.name} liked your workout"
    ...
  end
```

The issue I kept hitting was that it was common for a user to immediately unlike, right after liking something. This meant that the Like object was no more when the delayed_job tried to execute, and I'd get lots of "RecordNotFound" errors.

Now I have transitioned the delay call to a class method that does the object lookup in the background and returns if it no longer exists. Here's the new structure

```
  def background_send_push_notifications
    Like.delay.send_push_notifications(self.id)
  end

  def self.send_push_notifications(id)
    like = Like.find_by_id(id)
    like.send_push_notifications unless like.nil?
  end

  def send_push_notifications
    message = "#{self.user.name} liked your workout"
    ...
  end
```

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 2):

The Like object does not exist, so the method with rescue is not even being called.

Try defining your delayed method as a class method, not an instance method. That way, delayed job will be able to execute the method, even if the instance does not exist. E.g.,

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base

...

def self.send_push_notifications(like_id=nil)
  begin
    like = Like.find like_id
    user = like.message.user
    message = "#{like.user.name} liked your workout"
    Urbanairship::push_now(user, message, ["message", like.message.id]) if like.user != user
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    # Do nothing
  end
end

...

end
```

Comment: No, that's not quite right then. Delayed_job does retry failed jobs. It keeps a count, and retries up to n times, where n is configurable (default is 25 I believe). The more times it fails, the longer it waits before retrying again. The DelayedJob.retry_at attribute is the time it will try next. Looking more closely now, I think your rescue is not invoked because the Like object does not exist. Redefine send_push_notifications as a class method, not an instance method, then delayed_job can call it even if the object does not exist. I'll edit the answer if you need more clarification.

Comment: More clarification would be appreciated. I can tell you that I'm checking the retry attribute and it's "0" on these jobs, while with other failed jobs, I do see being retired multiple times.